# how to convert a asp website to wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, asp-classic, seo

i've a small website(with few of pages-- max 20) on asp running on windows server since last 3 years with a lot of traffic and all the pages are indexed and ranked high by google and other search engines, but now i decided to convert my existing asp website to wordpress on that same domain and host.i'll request the godaddy to change my hosting server from windows to linux, and that i'll install wordpress there and i'll recreate all 20 pages there, but the matter is that i'll lose my all traffic.is there anyway to redirect those asp indexed links to my new wordpress posts?
any kind of help will be appreciated-- Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use 301 redirect to redirect all your old asp urls to the new wordpress urls using htaccess.

http://ndesign-studio.com/blog/301-htaccess-redirect

You have only 20 pages so it would be easy for you to do it manually i think. Thanks

I found the following plugins to easily manage 301 redirects. Please use any of the one given below.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/screenshots/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-301-redirects/screenshots/

You just need to put the old asp url without the domain name and the new wordpess url with domain name. Thanks

Comment: +1 Also, make sure to setup Webmaster Tools. After you launch the new site, periodically check the Page Crawl errors report to find any pages you might have missed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vasanthan-- well, actually i will install the new wordpress on that same host and domain now where that old asp(the one i want to convert to wordpress) site resides, so i must delete all those asp file, now don't you think that the deletion will turn all those links dead? am totally new to this concept and never done something like that before.do you've any other better idea with which i can successfully my old asp website to wordpress on that same domain and host?

Comment: You don't need the asp files with in the server. I have updated my answer. Please check it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the existing SE rankings must be the top priority and for that you have no other option but use 301 redirect.

It's good to know how 301 redirect works; so this article may be useful;
http://www.seochat.com/c/a/Search-Engine-Optimization-Help/WordPress-301-Redirect-Tips-and-Techniques/

Since you will be porting your site into wordpress, it makes a lot of sense to use a known plug in for this particular task.

As always, download a known/rated/trustworthy/uptodate plug in.

Here is one that fits the bill, for you. 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-301-redirects/

HTH